# How do I insert a web page within my web page using frames

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to insert a iframe on my website, http://freefreemarkets.com, that allows me to insert the website showing what I am selling on eBay.

I have never created an iframe before.

Comment: I assume you mean an iframe?

Comment: What's the specific question, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="http://www.website.com"></iframe>
```

And you can edit how you want by adding stuff like:

`width="400" height="215" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"` etc..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), by specifying the `src` attribute:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

Some websites doesn't support to be embedded in iframe, be careful.